# cryptozombie external modifier

Tags: modifiers

One of the tutorials in [crypto zombies](https://cryptozombies.io) mentions about `external` function.

```
contract KittyInterface {
  function getKitty(uint256 _id) external view returns (
    bool isGestating,
    bool isReady,
    uint256 cooldownIndex,
    uint256 nextActionAt,
    uint256 siringWithId,
    uint256 birthTime,
    uint256 matronId,
    uint256 sireId,
    uint256 generation,
    uint256 genes
  );
}

contract ZombieFeeding is ZombieFactory {

  KittyInterface kittyContract;

  function setKittyContractAddress(address _address) external onlyOwner {
    kittyContract = KittyInterface(_address);
  }
```

Here, `setKittyContractAddress` is used to change the address in case of emergency. Why does it have to be declared as `external`?

because it sounds like you have to deploy another contract just to change kitty contract address.

ex:

```
contract ZombieFeedingInterface {
  function setKittyContractAddress(address _address) external;
}

contract Test {
    address zfAddress = 0x......;
    ZombieFeeding zombieFeeding = ZombieFeedingInterface(zfAddress);

    function changeKittyContractAddress(address _address) private onlyOwner {
        zombieFeeding.setKittyContractAddress(_address);
    }
}
```

and also create a separate html page (UI) to pass new `address` to this function.

Isn't `setKittyContractAddress` better to be declared as `internal` or `private`, so the owner doesn't have to create another contract and thus can handle it easily with the existing contract?

What's the benefit of `external` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions that are marked `private` or `internal` can only be called from another function in the contract itself (or a derived contract in the case of `internal`).

If you want to be able to call the function yourself, you need to mark it `public` or `external`. Yes, you can then call it from another contract, but more typically you'll call it directly by sending a transaction.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/contracts.html#visibility-and-getters may help.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I ask you why `setKittyContractAddress` is declared as `external` when you can declare it as `public` and call it without creating another contract. Since it is `external` creation of a separate contract is inevitable to call the function. This is the part where I am quite confused.

Comment: `public` is a superset of `external` that also asked internal calls. I can't figure out where you got the idea that you would need to create a separate contract, so I'm not sure how to convince you otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, that should read "also *supports* internal calls."